# How to disable ActiveMQ web site http://localhost:8161/

Tags: activemq-classic

I am a simple admin who is trying to stop users from logging into ActiveMQ as part of a security audit. We don't use this webpage at all so I want to disable this page all together. Which configs should I change in order to achieve this?

This is the page that I get after I get to sign in with username and password. I just need to disable this page completely.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable the embedded Web console, you simply need to comment out, or remove, the import element that imports the Jetty configuration into your broker's configuration file `activemq.xml`:

```xml
<beans  ... >
    <broker ... >
        ...
    </broker>
    <!-- <import resource="jetty.xml"/>  -->
</beans>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Tim and Justin. This works.